# How can I compile 32 bit ARM in a 64 bit RaspberryPi?

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compiling

I am doing some exercise with ARM 32, but in a 64 bit RaspberryPi.

Here is the code:

```
.global main

main:
        mov r0,#0
        mov r1,#5
        push {lr,ip}
        bl factorial
        pop {lr,ip} 
        bx lr

factorial:
        cmp r1,#1
        moveq pc,lr
        sub r1,r1,#1
        mul r0,r1,r0
        b factorial
```

If I try to compile factorial.s, I receive a bunch of errors:

```
cc    factorial.s   -o factorial
factorial.s: Assembler messages:
factorial.s:4: Error: operand 1 must be an integer register -- `mov r0,#0'
factorial.s:5: Error: operand 1 must be an integer register -- `mov r1,#5'
factorial.s:6: Error: unknown mnemonic `push' -- `push {lr,ip}'
factorial.s:8: Error: unknown mnemonic `pop' -- `pop {lr,ip}'
factorial.s:9: Error: unknown mnemonic `bx' -- `bx lr'
factorial.s:12: Error: operand 1 must be an integer or stack pointer register -- `cmp r1,#1'
factorial.s:13: Error: unknown mnemonic `moveq' -- `moveq pc,lr'
factorial.s:14: Error: operand 1 must be an integer or stack pointer register -- `sub r1,r1,#1'
factorial.s:15: Error: operand 1 must be a SIMD vector register -- `mul r0,r1,r0'
make: *** [<builtin>: factorial] Error 1
```

I think it's due to the fact I'm compiling ARM32 inside a 64bit Raspberry.

How can I compile ARM32 inside a 64 bit RaspberryPi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use a 32 bit version of Linux with your RaspberryPI.

This being said, you would need to install a toolchain such as `arm-linux-gnueabihf` on your 64 bit system.
If your Linux system is Debian-based, you can list the available packages by executing the following command:

`sudo apt-cache search gnueabihf`

An alternative would be to build binutils from scratch:

```
wget https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.35.tar.xz
tar Jxf binutils-2.35.tar.xz
mkdir binutils
cd binutils
../binutils-2.35/configure --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --prefix=/usr/local
make all
sudo make install

/usr/local/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-as -o factorial.o factorial.s
factorial.s: Assembler messages:
factorial.s:6: Warning: register range not in ascending order
factorial.s:8: Warning: register range not in ascending order
```

After replacing `push {lr,ip}` by `push {ip, lr}`  and `pop {lr, ip}` by `pop {ip, lr}`:

```
/usr/local/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-as -o factorial.o factorial.s
/usr/local/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -d factorial.o

factorial.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   e3a00000        mov     r0, #0
   4:   e3a01005        mov     r1, #5
   8:   e92d5000        push    {ip, lr}
   c:   eb000001        bl      18 <factorial>
  10:   e8bd5000        pop     {ip, lr}
  14:   e12fff1e        bx      lr

00000018 <factorial>:
  18:   e3510001        cmp     r1, #1
  1c:   01a0f00e        moveq   pc, lr
  20:   e2411001        sub     r1, r1, #1
  24:   e0000091        mul     r0, r1, r0
  28:   eafffffa        b       18 <factorial>
```

Comment: I installed the gnueabihf 32 bit toolchain as you suggested and I am now able to compile the file. But I am not able to execute it, it says: 
-bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory
Is there something I can do?

Comment: Yes, you can install the 32 bit libraries required for executing a 32 bit program on a 64 bit system.On an Ubuntu system, this could be done I guess by executing  `apt-get install libc6:armhf libstdc++6:armhf`. Which distribution are you using ?  please augment your question with the answer - thanks.

Comment: I am using kali for raspberry. Also `libc6-armhf-cross` is already installed and if I write `sudo apt search libstdc++6 | grep armhf` there aren't results.

Comment: Try adding the `armhf` architecture, then try installing the libraries again:
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf` then `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: thanks for helping me. what do you mean for "Install the libraries again"? I have to remove them and install again?

Comment: No, if you already successfully executed  `sudo apt-get install libc6:armhf libstdc++6:armhf`. At the point where you will think I answered your question, please accept it - this would be gratifying for me - thanks.

Please note that your program does not exit properly: one possible exit sequence could be:

        mov r0, #0 // return code
        mov r7, #1  // linux exit system call
        svc #0 // execute system call

Comment: it works if I install these libraries with: `sudo apt-get install libc6:armhf libstdc++6:armhf` Thanks!!